# CSS Selector - Get next element

Tags: css-selectors

I am having the following HTML:

```
<div class="comp-top col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Product</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">This product</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Category</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">Test-Category</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to select the text `This product` and `Test-Category`. Any suggestions how to target the next element after `Product` and `Category`.

Thank you!

Comment: Required nodes have `comp-value` class name, so why not just to select them with `div.comp-value` or `div.comp-stat + div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by select. But if you mean to get the selector to access them this would be the answer:

```
div.comp-top.col-sm-6 > div> div.col-6.comp-value{
   background-color:grey;
}
```

Or alternatively:

`div.comp-top.col-sm-6 > div > div:nth-child(2)` with the `(x)` being the x element on div.

If you want to select both of them then you could use `(even)` for selecting the even element on div.

```css
div.comp-top.col-sm-6 > div > div:nth-child(2){
   color:blue;
}

div.comp-top.col-sm-6 > div > div:nth-child(4){
   color:green;
}

/*div.comp-top.col-sm-6 > div > div:nth-child(even){
   background-color:grey;
}commented code above is to get even element, below to select by comp-value class*/

div.comp-top.col-sm-6 > div> div.col-6.comp-value{
   background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="comp-top col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Product</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">This product</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Category</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">Test-Category</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could check ***[here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css_selectors.asp)*** for more reference of ***CSS selector***.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `.row .col-6:nth-child(even)` , it will select both This Product and Test Category.